# How to declare uninitialized variable in abstract class in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class

I want to declare an abstract class which has a variable to be initialized in its subclasses. For example, let's say we have an abstract class called Country, and a subclass called United States. (I know, usually you'd make United States an instance of Country, but I'm just using this as an example so let's assume this is the design we are going for.) I want to have a `public final Set<String>` called bigCities which is declared but uninitialized in Country, but will be initialized in United States as something like {"New York", "Los Angeles", "Chicago"}. How would I accomplish this?

(I apologize if it's been asked before, but my question is rather difficult to formulate precise search terms for. Every time I've tried to search on Google or StackOverflow I've gotten questions that are similar to but not what I'm looking for.)

Comment: I would probably have a constructor in the super class that takes that kind of parameter, so the subclass must explicitely call it with a value

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Stack Overflow is meant to help with problems after you've exhausted your own resources.  This is a pretty basic question, so while it would be easy to provide an answer, the answer isn't going to address your underlying confusion (because we can't see where you're getting stuck)

Comment: I have like 50 of these variables just like bigCities. I'd rather not have to make all of them arguments of a function, as that would make the code look very messy. Is there a way around that?

Comment: @user477766 Um, that sounds like you have a poor design then.

Comment: @njzk2 should have added that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to define your property `bigCities` as `final` it has to be initialized within the constructor of the class, either `Country` or `UnitedStates` in your case.

```
public abstract class Country {
  public final Set<String> bigCities;
  public Country(Set<String> bigCities) {
    this.bigCities = bigCities;
  }
}
```

In that case the subclass of `Country` has to call the the parent's constructor with the specified argument.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can do this. You can have the Country constructor have a parameter called bigCities, and a subclass such as the UnitedStates would call super(cities, otherArgs).

Alternatively, you can make an abstract method like this

```
protected abstract Set<String> getBigCities();
```

and then in the Country constructor, set bigCities to the implementation of that method.

```
bigCities = getBigCities();
```

Comment: In this case you cannot make an abstract method because the property `bigCities` is declared as `final`.

Comment: It is also a bad practice to call non-final methods in a constructor as you describe; there are no guarantees as to their behavior in the subclass.

Comment: @Manuel Are you sure? I just ran a quick test and it seems to work fine.

Comment: @kabb then you didn't test what you just described while having the field declared `final`.

Comment: Definitely have the field declared final. Maybe you're misreading what I'm suggesting, it most definitely compiles and runs fine.

Comment: oic, you're returning it from the abstract method to the constructor and setting it there. I did read that part wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
abstract class Country {

    public final Set<String> bigCities;

    protected Country(String... bigCities) {
        this.bigCities = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(bigCities));
    }

}

class USA extends Country {
    USA() {
        super("NY", "Chicago");
    }
}
```